# Minecraft crashes on world load with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

On the "Loading World Building Terrain" screen minecraft freezes up and crashes for a minute or two, and then what happens is it crashes. Here is the crash report.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Surprise! Haha. Well, this is awkward.

Time: 8/26/15 4:53 PM
Description: Updating screen events

java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at rd.a(SourceFile:40)
    at rd.b(SourceFile:37)
    at up.c(SourceFile:10)
    at rc.a(SourceFile:104)
    at bsu.a(SourceFile:1914)
    at bwf.a(SourceFile:210)
    at bxf.a(SourceFile:342)
    at bwf.a(SourceFile:350)
    at bxf.k(SourceFile:405)
    at bxf.p(SourceFile:382)
    at bsu.r(SourceFile:1473)
    at bsu.as(SourceFile:877)
    at bsu.a(SourceFile:314)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:120)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:128)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:57)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:126)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:449)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:647)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:83)
    ... 28 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at rd.a(SourceFile:40)
    at rd.b(SourceFile:37)
    at up.c(SourceFile:10)
    at rc.a(SourceFile:104)
    at bsu.a(SourceFile:1914)
    at bwf.a(SourceFile:210)
    at bxf.a(SourceFile:342)
    at bwf.a(SourceFile:350)
    at bxf.k(SourceFile:405)
    at bxf.p(SourceFile:382)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: bxq
Stacktrace:
    at bsu.r(SourceFile:1473)
    at bsu.as(SourceFile:877)
    at bsu.a(SourceFile:314)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:120)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 3206944208 bytes (3058 MB) / 4116185088 bytes (3925 MB) up to 4116185088 bytes (3925 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 13, tallocated: 95
    Launched Version: 1.8
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 GL version 4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.3958, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

If anyone could help that would be awesome.

Comment: Take a look at this [FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question) and try to [edit] your question with as much information as you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to first offer you a way to find a solution faster. Take the first line of the crash dump and google search it. Then dig.

I found this:

> This issue is most commonly caused by a broken installation of Avast!
> free edition Anti-virus software. A reinstallation of Avast! and a
> reboot usually fixes it. McAfee anti-virus software (and derivatives)
> are also know to cause this issue, and currently the only known
> solution is to uninstall this software to correct the problem.

As a solution according to Mojang bug tracker [here](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-34749)

This may be caused by other virus scanners. Try to offer your virus scanner a way to ignore / safelist minecraft. Otherwise disable virus scanner.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is most likely caused because the world is from a newer version. I had that issue a few weeks ago, when had to go back to `1.6.4`. I couldn't open any world. And when I created one, I could.
Does this work for you, or when you create a world does it still crash?

Comment: The question states that this happens when *creating a new world*.

Comment: The crash log states that this happens in 1.8