# Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop how to resolve?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

"Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create a child event loop" but I have a different antivirus from the ones you guys have been mentioning on all the other questions. I am using Quick Heal total security, does this affect anything because also some other games of mine are not working. Please help.

Comment: Any antivirus can cause a trigger, rlly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft crashes on world load with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233370/minecraft-crashes-on-world-load-with-java-lang-illegalstateexception-failed-to)

Comment: Try reinstalling Quick Heal and restarting your PC, like the accepted answer in the duplicate suggests. If that doesn't work, you can say so in your question. Until then, there is no reason to assume your situation is different.

Comment: ok, will try, thank you!

Comment: Resolved, thanks!